# <canvas> element in Chrome randomly flipping vertical before toDataURL()

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, canvas

I present to you, dear reader, a vexing bug that I cannot reproduce locally. However, I have gotten many reports from end-users, which seem to be increasing in frequency.

If you are an advanced user of `<canvas>` elements in Chrome, please continue reading, as I am completely baffled.

---

I use `<canvas>` elements to render full-size iPhone and iPad screenshots. I have a method that renders the canvas, which looks something like:

1. set the size of the canvas to iPhone resolution (640x1136) — **possibly important**: this canvas might have been rendered at a smaller resolution before
2. fill with background color (0, 0, width, height)
3. draw text at the top
4. draw an image of a phone in the middle of the bottom
5. draw a screenshot image on top of that phone image
6. call `toDataURL()` on the canvas to extract the image as a JPEG

Recently, after months of nobody reporting any problems, we've had several reports from different people reporting exported images being "messed up".

The images they send us are the correct size, BUT rather than the images containing the canvas area at `(0, 0, width, height)`, the resulting images seem to contain the image data from `(0, height, width, height)` — offset by the height of the canvas and then **flipped vertically** for some reason.

Here is what this looks like:

[image]

As shown in this image, the content of the `<canvas>` element itself is seemingly not in the end-result image generated by toDataURL(); rather, the end-result image seems to contain the flipped image data from below the actual area of the `<canvas>`.

**Important debugging information**:

- There are no calls to `setTransform()`, `scale()` or `translate()` anywhere in my code
- These canvas elements are not visible to the end-user
- This does not seem to affect Safari
- I have users reporting the same output in Chrome incognito windows, so it is probably not the result of an extension
- The code seems to be rendering the images in the correct locations on the canvas — the screenshot and phone appear in the correct place, and the background color is not present (since it is only drawn to `0, 0, width, height` and not beyond)
- Reports seem to be increasing in frequency, but still probably only 5-10% of Chrome end-users

Any ideas as to a root cause?

---

**UPDATE**: I have fixed the issue through trial and error. In the original implementation, I borrowed a "preview" low-resolution canvas to render the full-resolution image before calling toDataURL — my fix created a new canvas at the new size for the final rendering, rather than reusing the lower-resolution original canvas.

I'd still love to know the original cause. I think it has something to do with resizing `<canvas>` elements in code before calling `drawImage()` or something, but I can't reproduce it in order to investigate further.

Comment: The only thing I can think of with this amount of information is that it's a bug in Chrome itself and it's slowly getting exposed to users via auto-updates. Do you have any versioning information from your users? Have you tried Canary? Do you have a publically accessible page where this can be viewed?

Comment: I have not been able to reproduce in Chrome Canary. This only happens during final render of 20+ sequential high-resolution images, not during user-visible preview. Can't link to a user-provided example, but here is one of mine that should trigger it as well in theory: https://launchkit.io/screenshots/dashboard/x1M8973_0-c/preview (requires login to do full-res rendering pass)

Comment: I wonder if maybe in a recent iOS update (Dec. 10?) they changed the EXIF data that is included in screenshots and this is messing with either the original drawing on the canvas and/or the extraction via `toDataURL` (since it would be stripped there).

Comment: Tried to reproduce with some new 9.2 screenshots from an upside-down iPad to no avail. Also with customer data (same images they used) I could not reproduce, which leads me to believe it's certain OS/hardware...?